# What does a capacitor in parallel with a pull up resistor at the drain of a N mosfet do?

Tags: capacitor, nmos, emissions

I am analyzing a past design that uses a GPIO to toggle the N mosfet on and off. The resistor is just a super long winded trace on a separate board. There is a capacitor in parallel with the resistor. What is the role of the capacitor? I am having issues with this circuit since when the mosfet is OFF I am seeing the emissions goes **up by 10dB** compared to when the mosfet is ON. Debugging further I notice that if I remove the capacitor, the high emissions go away regardless if the mosfet is on or off. From my understanding the capacitor was there to filter out differential mode noise but it seems to be causing more issues. Just trying to understand what the role of the capacitor is there for. Thanks for the help.

[image: Mosfet with 100ohm pull up and capacitor]

Comment: "Super long winding trace"  - Are you sure it wasn't meant to be an inductor rather than a resistor?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by 'emissions'? How are you measuring it?

Comment: You need to tell us what the circuit is intended purpose is, not just what it does (specifically, what is R and the purpose of toggling power through it). Telling us the NMOS toggles the resistor on and off is like saying the purpose of a a car is to spin its wheels, rather than saying it is transportation. Is there really nothing else to the circuit? It doesn't connect anywhere else?

Comment: @JRE The long trace is around 100ohm, I believe it was intended to be a resistor to warm up a section of the circuit. If it does act like an inductor, what negative affects does the capacitor have when in parallel?

Comment: @kanooI do this with a spectrum analyzer in an EMI tent, I can see the increase in 10dB when toggling the GPIO.

Comment: @DKNguyen, the R is just suppose to act like a heater. There is nothing else to the circuit.

Comment: Does the GPIO constantly switch on and off?  Like, as a pulse width modulation scheme or something, or does it stay on and off for long periods?  In other words, what does the output from the controller look like?

Comment: That cap might be intended to be a snubber (an improper RC snubber without the series R) for when you interrupt current to the winding trace if it is inductive. Not how I would have done it though, but its cheaper. Not sure it's really necessary in this case either since snubbers tend to improve EMI. It might just be promoting fast edges here rather than slowing. It's also possible it's a bad design an the designer was hoping the cap would smooth the voltage across the heating resistor. I could see that happening.

Comment: The GPIO does not toggle on and off constantly. It depends on the ambient temperature. It will stay on and off for long periods of time. That capacitor is also on a different board from the long winding trace. I think the intent was to prevent noise from getting onto the board with the long winding trace

Comment: Thanks DKNguyen, I can scope out the output with the capacitor populated and unpopulated to see if the edges are faster with it populated.

Comment: If it is to prevent noise it should be as close as possible to the source (ie, the heater) not the destination of the noise. Even then I think things would be bad with the rapid charging. Also, by fast edges I mean current edges.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's quite far, and the resistive heater (long winding trace board) connects to the other board through an inch of 30AWG cable. Surprising that even if the cap is not by the source it has negative effect rather than not do anything. I will scope the output today and see why that is. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why are you pulling down 100ohm to GND? is there a signal between the mosfet and R2?

Comment: @AntonIngemarson, the 100ohm is not pulled to ground. It's pulled up to 5V as seen in the image above. There is no other signal between mosfet and R2 except what is posted